# Is it a good design to inject services as factories?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, dependency-injection

I have been reading Mark Seemann's excellent book on DI and hope to implement it in my next WPF project. However I have a query regarding object lifetime. So far, most examples seem to explain the repository pattern per request for MVC applications. In WPF there isn't really an alternative to this (I think). Seeing as the object graph of the entire application is constructed in the composition root, how can I make sure that my unit-of-work stuff is working properly. For example:

```
public class ContextFactory : IContextFactory
{
    DBContext context;

    public ContextFactory()
    {
        context = new MyDBContext();
    }

    public DBContext GetContext()
    {
        return context;
    }
}

public class ItemOneRepository() : IItemOneRepository
{
    DBContext context;

    public ItemOneRepository(IContextFactory contextFactory)
    {
        this.context = contextFactory.GetContext();
    }

    public IEnumerable GetItems()
    {
        return context.ItemOnes;
    }
}

public class ItemTwoRepository() : IItemTwoRepository
{
    DBContext context;

    public ItemTwoRepository(IContextFactory contextFactory)
    {
        this.context = contextFactory.GetContext();
    }

    public IEnumerable GetItemsByItemOneID(int itemOneID)
    {
        return context.ItemTwos.Where(i => i.itemOneID == itemOneID);
    }
}

public class ThingService : IThingService
{
    IItemOneRepository itemOneRepo;
    IItemTwoRepository itemTwoRepo;

    public ThingService(
        IItemOneRepository itemOneRepository,
        IItemTwoRepository itemTwoRepository)
    {
        itemOneRepo = itemOneRepository;
        itemTwoRepo = itemTwoRepository;
    }

    public IEnumerable Things GetThing()
    {
        var ItemOnes = itemOneRepo.GetItems();

        return ItemOnes.Select(i =>
            new Thing(
                i.FieldOne,
                i.FieldFour,
                itemRepoTwo.GetItemsByItemOneID(i.ID)
            )
        );
    }
}
```

In this case the MyDBContext instance is created through ContextFactory in the composition root. ItemOneRepository and ItemTwoRepository are using the same unit-of-work (MyDBContext), but so is the rest of the application which is plainly wrong. What if I changed the repositories to accept a DBContext instead of ContextFactory and added a ThingServiceFactory class like:

```
public ThingServiceFactory : IThingServiceFactory
{
    IContextFactory contextFactory;

    public ThingServiceFactory(IContextFactory factory)
    {
        contextFactory = factory;
    }

    public IThingService Create()
    {
        MyDBContext context = contextFactory.Create();
        ItemOneRepository itemOneRepo = new ItemOneRepository(context);
        ItemOneRepository itemTwoRepo = new ItemTwoRepository(context);
        return new ThingService(itemOneRepo, itemTwoRepo);
    }
}
```

This is better as I can now pass the ThingServiceFactory to my ViewModels instead of an instance of ThingService (complete with DBContext). I can then create a unit-of-work whenever I need one and instantly dispose of it when I’ve finished. However, is this really the correct approach. Do I really need to write a factory for every unit-of-work operation I need? Surely there is a better way...

Comment: Its an interesting problem, and will likely get an answer here.  But I would suggest you'd find more help over on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) for optimization help or possibly [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) if its architecture ideas you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's IMO only one good solution to this problem and that is to apply a [command-based](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2011/meanwhile-on-the-command-side-of-my-architecture/) and [query-based](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2011/meanwhile-on-the-query-side-of-my-architecture/) application design.

When you define a single `ICommandHandler<TCommand>` abstraction to define business transactions, you can inject closed versions of that interface into any form that needs this. Say for instance you have a "move customer" 'command' operation:

```
public class MoveCustomer
{
    public Guid CustomerId;
    public Address NewAddress;
}
```

And you can create a class that will be able to execute this command:

```
public class MoveCustomerHandler : ICommandHandler<MoveCustomer>
{
    private readonly DBContext context;

    // Here we simply inject the DbContext, not a factory.
    public MoveCustomerHandler(DbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void Handle(MoveCustomer command)
    {
        // write business transaction here.
    }
}
```

Now your WPF Windows class can depend on `ICommandHandler<MoveCustomer>` as follows:

```
public class MoveCustomerWindow : Window
{
    private readonly ICommandHandler<MoveCustomer> handler;

    public MoveCustomerWindows(ICommandHandler<MoveCustomer> handler)
    {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Here we call the command handler and pass in a newly created command.
        this.handler.Handle(new MoveCustomer
        {
            CustomerId = this.CustomerDropDown.SelectedValue,
            NewAddress = this.AddressDropDown.SelectedValue,
        });
    }
}
```

Since `MoveCustomerWindow` lives for quite some time, it will drag on its dependencies for as long as it lives. If those dependencies shouldn't live that long (for instance your `DbContext`) you will be in trouble and Mark Seemann calls this problem [Captive Dependency](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/).

But since we now have a single `ICommandHandler<TCommand>` abstraction between our presentation layer and our business layer, it becomes very easy to define a single decorator that allows postponing the creation of the real `MoveCustomerHandler`. For instance:

```
public class ScopedCommandHandlerProxy<TCommand> : ICommandHandler<TCommand>
{
    private readonly Func<ICommandHandler<TCommand>> decorateeFactory;
    private readonly Container container;

    // We inject a Func<T> that is able to create the command handler decoratee 
    // when needed.
    public ScopedCommandHandlerProxy(
        Func<ICommandHandler<TCommand>> decorateeFactory,
        Container container)
    {
        this.decorateeFactory = decorateeFactory;
        this.container = container;
    }

    public void Handle(TCommand command)
    {
        // Start some sort of 'scope' here that allows you to have a single 
        // instance of DbContext during that scope. How to do this depends 
        // on your DI library (if you use any).
        using (container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
             // Create a wrapped handler inside the scope. This way it will get 
             // a fresh DbContext.
             ICommandHandler<TCommand> decoratee =this.decorateeFactory.Invoke();

             // Pass the command on to this handler.
             decoratee.Handle(command);
        }
    }
}
```

This sounds a bit complex, but this completely allows you to hide the fact that a new DbContext is needed from the client Window and you hide this complexity as well from your business layer; you can simply inject a `DbContext` into your handler. Both sides know nothing about this little peace of infrastructure.

Of course you still have to wire this up. Without a DI library you do something like this:

```
var handler = new ScopedCommandHandlerProxy<MoveCustomerCommand>(
    () => new MoveCustomerCommandHandler(new DbContext()),
    container);
```

How to register this in a DI library is completely depending on the library of choice, but with Simple Injector you do it as follows:

```
// Register all command handler implementation all at once.
container.Register(
    typeof(ICommandHandler<>), 
    typeof(ICommandHandler<>).Assembly);

// Tell Simple Injector to wrap each ICommandHandler<T> implementation with a
// ScopedCommandHandlerProxy<T>. Simple Injector will take care of the rest and 
// will inject the Func<ICommandHandler<T>> for you. The proxy can be a
// singleton, since it will create the decoratee on each call to Handle.
container.RegisterDecorator(
    typeof(ICommandHandler<>), 
    typeof(ScopedCommandHandlerProxy<>),
    Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

This is just one of the many advantages that this type of design gives you. Other advantages is that it makes much easier to apply all sorts of cross-cutting concerns such as audit trailing, logging, security, validation, de-duplication, caching, deadlock-prevention or retry mechanisms, etc, etc. The possibilities are endless.

Comment: I was with you up until "Captive Dependency". I'll keep going and try and get my head around it.

Comment: I think my main confusion is over the Container class. Is this just an empty class? Is it's only purpose to provide a scope that the decoratee is created/disposed within? Wouldn't the decoratee fall out of scope anyway at the end of the Handle() method?

Comment: @BoroDrummer: The `Container` class is normally the class that you use to define all the mappings between abstractions and implementations in your application - if you use a DI library. In my example I use Simple Injector.

Comment: @BoroDrummer: You can't say anything about the scope of the decoratee from perspective of the decorator. A decoratee could possibly be reused, but I think you will often see that it falls out of scope after that handle method.

Comment: Surely the scope of the decoratee will only continue outside of Handle() if it is passed to another process that lives longer than the Handle() method itself. How would SimpleInjector deal with this in terms of using BeginLifeTimeScope()?... I guess that is another discussion :)

Comment: @BoroDrummer: The comments section would indeed not be the right place to discuss. I even think that Stackoverflow wouldn't be a good place to discuss. If you're really interested, you can ask this at the [Simple Injector discussion form](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/discussions/create).

Answer (score 0):

> ItemOneRepository and ItemTwoRepository are using the same
>   unit-of-work (MyDBContext), but so is the rest of the application
>   which is plainly wrong.

If your factory is registered with a transient lifecycle, you will get a new instance every time it's injected, which will be a new DBContext each time.

However, I would recommend a more explicit unit of work implementation:

```
public DBContext GetContext() //I would rename this "Create()"
{
    return new MyDBContext();
}
```

And:

```
public IEnumerable GetItemsByItemOneID(int itemOneID)
{
   using (var context = contextFactory.Create())
    {
       return context.ItemTwos.Where(i => i.itemOneID == itemOneID);
    }
}
```

This gives you fine-grained control over the unit of work and transaction.

You might also ask yourself if the repositories are gaining you anything vs. just using the context directly via the factory.  Depending on the complexity of your application, the repositories may be unnecessary overhead.

Comment: But with this method every repository has its own DBContext. I lose the possibility of unit-of-work across multiple repositories.

Comment: In those cases, you can wrap the calls in a TransactionScope.  Another option is to pass the UOW into the repository method, and make the creation of the UOW the caller's responsibility.  Again, consider whether you need the repositories at all.